# Any way to get correct conversion for unicode text format data to csv in python?

Tags: python, csv, python-unicode

I am accessing dataset that lives on ftp server. after I download the data, I used `pandas` to read it as `csv` but I got an encoding error. The file has `csv` file extension but after I opened the file with MS excell, data was in `Unicode Text` format. I want to make conversion of those dataset that stored in Unicode text format. How can I make this happen? Any idea to get this done?

**my attempt**:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os

def mydef():
defaultIP=''
username='cat'
password='cat'

ftp = FTP(defaultIP,user=username, passwd=password)
ftp.dir()

filenames=ftp.nlst() 

for filename in files:
    local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\me', filename)
    file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)

    file.close()

ftp.quit()
```

then I tried this to get correct encoding:

```
mydef.encode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

but this one is not working for me. I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089194/python-convert-bytes-unicode-tab-delimited-data-to-csv-file/51089703)

**the output of above code**:

here is output snippet of above code:

> b'\xff\xfeF\x00L\x00O\x00W\x00\t\x00C\x00T\x00Y\x00_\x00R\x00P\x00T\x00\t\x00R\x00E\x00P\x00O\x00R\x00T\x00E\x00R\x00\t\x00C\x00T\x00Y\x00_\x00P\x00T\x00N\x00\t\x00P\x00A\x00R\x00T\x00N\x00E\x00R\x00\t\x00C\x00O\x00M\x00M\x00O\x00D\x00I\x00T\x00Y\x00\t\x00D\x00E\x00S\x00C\x00R\x00I\x00P\x00T\x00I\x00O\x00N\x00\t'

**expected output**

the expected output of this dataset should be in normal `csv` data such as common trade data, but encoding doesn't work for me.

I used different encoding for getting the correct conversion of `csv` format data but none of them works for me. How can I make that work? any idea to get this done? thanks

Comment: if it is CSV file then open it in normal text editor to see what you have. It doesn't look like CSV file. Or maybe it doesn't use `utf-8` but other encoding - ie. `utf-16`. `utf-16 sometimes is used on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have to change it - now I remove 2 bytes at the beginning (`BOM`) and one byte at the end because data is incomplete (every char needs 2 bytes)

---

It seems it is not `utf-8` but `utf-16` with `BOM`

If I remove first two bytes (`BOM` - `Bytes Order Mark`) and last byte at the end because it is incomplete (every char needs two bytes) and use `decode('utf-16-le')`

```
b'F\x00L\x00O\x00W\x00\t\x00C\x00T\x00Y\x00_\x00R\x00P\x00T\x00\t\x00R\x00E\x00P\x00O\x00R\x00T\x00E\x00R\x00\t\x00C\x00T\x00Y\x00_\x00P\x00T\x00N\x00\t\x00P\x00A\x00R\x00T\x00N\x00E\x00R\x00\t\x00C\x00O\x00M\x00M\x00O\x00D\x00I\x00T\x00Y\x00\t\x00D\x00E\x00S\x00C\x00R\x00I\x00P\x00T\x00I\x00O\x00N\x00'.decode('utf-16-le')
```

then I get

```
'FLOW\tCTY_RPT\tREPORTER\tCTY_PTN\tPARTNER\tCOMMODITY\tDESCRIPTION'
```

---

**EDIT:** meanwhile I found also [Python - Decode UTF-16 file with BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459020/python-decode-utf-16-file-with-bom)

Comment: BOM in UTF-16 is 2 bytes, not 3.

Comment: I couldn't decode it so I removed third byte - but I found problem - text is incomplete and I have to remove last byte and then I can remove 2 bytes BOM at the beginning and decode.

Comment: @MarkRansom I changed it - I had to remove last bytes instead of third at the beginning.

Comment: @furas is there any more consistent solution instead of removing the third byte manually? since actual output snippet is a lot

Comment: read my current answer - now I remove only two bytes at beginning because BOM has 2 bytes - if you use full data then you don't have to remove third byte - but I had to remove because you gave incomplete data and it didn't work with last byte. in UTF-16 every char uses 2 bytes and data needs even number of bytes to decode it.